# Find the max date for similarly named items

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find a distinct list of order numbers from a database. The database would be laid out similar to this:

```
orderNumber    customer      createDate
---------------------------------------
001            123            2019-01-01
002            123            2019-01-23
003            456            2019-03-12
003R1          456            2019-03-22
004            456            2019-04-25
005            789            2019-05-21
005A1          789            2019-06-30
005R1          789            2019-07-12
```

R1 would be a refund of the order and A1 would be an adjustment for that order.

The result set I'm looking for is a list of distinct order numbers that only contains the most recent version of that order number. Example:

```
Results
orderNumber    customer       CreateDate
----------------------------------------
001            123            2019-01-01
002            123            2019-01-23
003R1          456            2019-03-22
004            456            2019-04-25
005R1          789            2019-07-12
```

I've tried a couple of different methods, but they either return each refund or adjustment or doesn't display the other distinct order numbers

```
select customer, orderNumber, createDate
from (select customer
        ,orderNumber
        ,createDate
        ,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by customer order by createDate desc) as RowNum
      from orders) as T
where RowNum = 1
```

The results of that above query would look like:

```
orderNumber    customer      createDate
---------------------------------------
002            123            2019-01-23
003R1          456            2019-03-22
005R1          789            2019-07-12
```

Is there a way to get each order number along with only the most current version of "duplicate" order numbers?

Comment: It would be faster and simpler to have a separate column for special flags like R1 and A1 that you populate on insert or with a trigger.

Comment: And which SQL database are you using? Postgres? MySQL? SQL Server?

Comment: Please post which database you are using. Oracle? mySQL? SQL Server?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've almost got it. You need to partition by the normalized orderNumber with the flag stripped off. Here I'm using `left` and `substring`, but you should use a more robust pattern match to get the first digits.

```
select
  left(orderNumber, 3) as cleanOrderNumber,
  substring(orderNumber, 4, 5) as flag,
  customer,
  createDate,
  row_number() over (partition by left(orderNumber, 3) order by createDate desc) as RowNum
from orders;

cleanOrderNumber    flag    customer    createDate              RowNum
001                         123         01/01/2019 00:00:00     1
002                         123         23/01/2019 00:00:00     1
003                 R1      456         22/03/2019 00:00:00     1
003                         456         12/03/2019 00:00:00     2
004                         456         25/04/2019 00:00:00     1
005                 R1      789         12/07/2019 00:00:00     1
005                 A1      789         30/06/2019 00:00:00     2
005                         789         21/05/2019 00:00:00     3
```

Then we can use that as a CTE and get the first row for each orderNumber.

```
with cleanOrders as (
select
  left(orderNumber, 3) as cleanOrderNumber,
  substring(orderNumber, 4, 5) as flag,
  customer,
  createDate,
  row_number() over (partition by left(orderNumber, 3) order by createDate desc) as RowNum
from orders
)
select *
from cleanOrders
where rowNum = 1;

cleanOrderNumber    flag    customer    createDate              RowNum
001                         123         01/01/2019 00:00:00     1
002                         123         23/01/2019 00:00:00     1
003                 R1      456         22/03/2019 00:00:00     1
004                         456         25/04/2019 00:00:00     1
005                 R1      789         12/07/2019 00:00:00     1
```

Note that if the `orderNumber` and `flag` were already separated in the table this would be easier and faster (they can be indexed). You could add new columns, populate them, and leave `orderNumber` as legacy.

Comment: Thank you so much Schwern! That is exactly what I needed to solve this problem! I applied that solution to my table and got the exact results I was looking for. You are a life saver! :)

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working as follows.
That's for DDL and sample data.

```sql
CREATE TABLE orders
    ([orderNumber] varchar(5), [customer] int, [createDate] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO orders
    ([orderNumber], [customer], [createDate])
VALUES
    ('001', 123, '2019-01-01 00:00:00'),
    ('002', 123, '2019-01-23 00:00:00'),
    ('003', 456, '2019-03-12 00:00:00'),
    ('003R1', 456, '2019-03-22 00:00:00'),
    ('004', 456, '2019-04-25 00:00:00'),
    ('005', 789, '2019-05-21 00:00:00'),
    ('005A1', 789, '2019-06-30 00:00:00'),
    ('005R1', 789, '2019-07-12 00:00:00')
;
```

And this is the actual query:

```sql
WITH ordersCTE AS (
  SELECT *, PATINDEX('%[a-z]%', orderNumber) AS firstLetterPosition
  FROM orders AS O)
, ComputedOrderNumber AS (
  SELECT *, CAST(CASE firstLetterPosition
      WHEN 0 THEN orderNumber
      ELSE LEFT(orderNumber, firstLetterPosition -1)
    END AS INT) as actualOrderNumber
  FROM ordersCTE)
, Ordered AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY actualOrderNumber ORDER BY createDate DESC) AS RN
  FROM ComputedOrderNumber
  )
SELECT *
FROM Ordered
WHERE RN = 1
```

This will attempt to extract the identity before ignoring any letters in `orderNumber` and then use it for partitioning the data.

But I would strongly advice to have a proper column to store the root of the `orderNumber`, computing this every single time is going to be very expensive.